# Git - Split current hunk into line so I can commit separately when use git add -p

Tags: git

I add two lines into my file

```
@@ -2,3 +2,5 @@ i am original.
 I am the second change.
 my 3rd line
 this is the 4th change
+I am 5th change
+I am 6 change
```

The 's' can not split it into line, any ideas? I know there is "manually edit hunk", but I don't think it can split the two lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you manually edit the hunk, you can get rid of the `+I am 6 change` line, and then commit. The `I am 6 change` line is still present in the original file (`git add -p`, even with editing hunks, does not touch the working tree), so you just add the file and commit again to get that change separately.